# Go Lang- Configure Swagger UI(http://localhost:4545/docs) and local host(http://localhost:4545) running at the same time on the same port

Tags: go, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I'm trying to implement swagger for Go-lang project. How to configure both Swagger UI(http://localhost:4545/docs) and local host(http://localhost:4545) running at the same on same port 4545. I can get response only on one interface(either swagger UI or localhost via postman at a time. Even our Dev Rest API's are configured on port 4545. How to get swagger UI up and running when the API's are already using 4545?

Comment: merge the two project(swagger ui and the api server) together?

Comment: essentially you are asking how two applications `swagger` server and `application` server can access the same port, correct?

Comment: Yes. We are trying to achieve this with go-swagger.

Comment: why does it have to be the same port